# ImageButton Border Transparency - How do I remove the square border around round image?

Tags: android, image

I think my image is transparent, but  I am seeing a grey background appearing around the edges of my image which is round.  So instead of nice transparent round ImageButton I am seeing square edges.  I need to provide height or it complains but now I have outline of grey/silver square instread of just round image.

Comment: Please note I am not sure if this is a border or background that I am seeing. I know it is not the images background.  Perhaps it is the background of the ImageButton.  The region that is not covered by the round image I am providing....

Comment: Either way it frames the buttons with the border of a square.

Comment: Post the code for the button and image.. Do you have any padding?

Comment: No there is no padding of the image and the image is transparent.  So this background is being set by android for the button area.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Set this attribute in your `ImageButton` XML `android:background="@null"`

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/yourimagename"
     android:id="@+id/thebuttonid"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:background="@null"
     />
```

Answer (score 17):

Or just set the background to Android's transparent color

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/yourimagename"
     android:id="@+id/thebuttonid"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     />
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use ImageButton.setBackgroundResource(int) (android:background attribute) which will get rid of that border.

Costi

Answer (score 0):

As told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027462/android-imagebutton-without-border-but-still-with-click-indication) you can declare it in the constructor like this:

```
Button button = new Button(context, null, android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context, null, android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
```