# Android ImageButton without border but still with click indication

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

How to create an ImageButton without border (just the image should be visible)? One could achieve this by setting `imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null)`, but this also removes the focus and selection colors.

The goal is that initially only the image without borders is visible. But when the user focuses/touches/clicks the image **this should be indicated by hightlighting the image** like regular buttons.

Solution in Java-Code for API 14 is preferred. Thank you!

Comment: did u tried in your imagebutton xml code by setting android:background="null". this will sets the transparent background

Comment: @Witek please look my answer I hope it help you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As has been mentioned, the `borderlessButtonStyle` built into the default themes on API11 and above is the simplest way to achieve this effect.  You mentioned you are creating your buttons in Java code instead of XML, so there are two options depending on how you need to apply the style.

**Option #1: Add it to the theme**

If all the `Button` or `ImageButton` instances in your application (or at least within the Activity) need to have this style applied, add the styling to your theme instead:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Default style for ImageButtons -->
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">?android:borderlessButtonStyle</item>
        <!-- Default style for Buttons -->
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">?android:borderlessButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

With this theme applied to your Application or Activity, you won't have to declare the style of each element, you can just declare them as

```
Button button = new Button(context);
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
```

And the styling will be pulled from the theme.

**Option #2: Declare it in the constructor**

If only a couple buttons need to be styled this way, you can pass the style attribute you want to apply directly to each view, like so:

```
Button button = new Button(context, null, android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context, null, android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
```

This version supplies a different default style attribute for the widget to use.

Comment: This does not work for me with <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> Any ideas for AppCompat?

Answer (score 7):

Use **borderlessButtonStyle** to ImageButton

```
 <ImageButton
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Delete"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
```

Ref : [Google I/O 2013 - Android Design for UI Developers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI)

Comment: Any idea, how to set the style attribute to ImageButton in Java code? Without having the ImageButton in any XML file?

Comment: I don't have any idea but I find one line from theme.xml  `<item name="borderlessButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonStyle</item>`

Answer (score 6):

Use a [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for the background like this:

**/res/drawable/my_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />  
</selector>
```

`my_drawable` is whatever drawable you want as your border.

Then your `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
  android:src="@drawable/your_bitmap" />
```

`your_bitmap` is your actual image.

Comment: But what is @drawable/my_drawable? I want the default Holo highlighting and focusing. I would like to do the opposite. Default drawables for pressed, focused,... and 'no image' for default. Is this somehow possible? Isn't it what every app with clickable images does?

Comment: @Witek - I would look into the source and copy it.

Comment: Which source file do you mean?

Comment: Take a look in `android-sdk\platforms\android-17\data\res` - all the buttons/drawables/layouts for holo are there. Replace `17` with whatever platform (>11) you have

Comment: I have copied the <selector> from btn_default_holo_light.xml. But then I get the following error for every <item>-line: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused').

Comment: @Witek put that selector xml in drawable folder

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is here in the Nick Butcher and  Roman Nurik  talk for Google I/O 2013 about android design for UI developers.

Min: 31:40:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI#t=31m40s

The only problem with this approach is that `style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"` is available for API 11 and above so if you want the same behaviour on any API before the 11, then you will have to stick with selectors.

By the way I highly recommend you to watch the whole talk because it is really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
imageButton.setClickable(true);
imageButton.setFocusable(true);
```

And it will works...

That's the way in your xml file :

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Hope this help

Comment: The image is clickable and the OnClickListener is executed. But the image still isn't highlighted when I touch it.

Answer (score 0):

*I hope this will help you. please give the background as transparent*

```
<ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/facebookbuttonanimation"
            android:background="#00000000"

            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can design different images for clicked/not clicked states and set them in the onTouchListener as shown in the selected answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-in-android) SO post.

Then you can set the image back to the previous image on post longclick or click.