# Android - How do I remove the ugly borders on imagebuttons?

Tags: android, xml, image, button, android-imagebutton

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbVNd.png

Pretty straight up question - How do I remove those grey borders?

The pictures (.png files) are just the stars, text and the white around it. Then when I add them as imagebuttons they add this ugly grey borders that I really don't want.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/starButton1"
        android:src="@drawable/star_pink_1"
        android:onClick="starButton1Clicked"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: You can use `ImageView` instead of it otherwise set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to image button.

Comment: you can create a shape in xml with border width and stroke width equal to 0.

Comment: @Nepster No need to do that long code. Transparent background will work.

Comment: android:background="@drawable/star_pink_1" instead of src may also work. You are right Piyush Gupta

Comment: Yeah. That's fine then. No need to make its to harder.

Comment: @Nepster, defining this as a background will not scale it and will look squeezed on different screens, so it is not a good idea...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageButton Border Transparancy - How do I remove the square border around round image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374066/imagebutton-border-transparancy-how-do-i-remove-the-square-border-around-round)

Comment: OPiatefuchs you are right . but it is an imageButton we can set ScaleType to fitXY . but I also prefer to do it using transparent Background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the xml attribute background to Your `ImageButton`:

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

what You see is the original button, Your src is just overlayed.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
android:background="@null"
```

this will make your imagebutton with no background.

Comment: it should be a comment

Comment: please clarify the issue with this?I have answered for his question.

Answer (score 2):

Both codes work fine for your query :

```
android:background="@null"
```

**OR**

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```