# Android Returns Error Upon Compiling After Declaring ImageButton's Background to Transparent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

So I'm having a few problems with compiling my app after declaring the `android:background` value of an `ImageButton` to `android:color/transparent"`. I've read this is the correct way to avoid having a grey border around the image from a relative post, which you can view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374066/imagebutton-border-transparency-how-do-i-remove-the-square-border-around-round).

The exact error message I'm getting is the following:

```
Error:error: 'android:color/transparent' is incompatible with attribute android:background (attr) reference|color.
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, so if anyone has any ideas, please give me a shout as this is beyond frustrating!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add @ before android:color/transparent
you need to write 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Thank you!! I can't believe I didn't notice that, it's always the small things you don't notice after hours of coding haha